# IOS app for a website

Tags: ios, credit-card

I'm starting making an app for a website that I own. I know some about programming with xcode but there's a lot of stuff that I don't know yet. Mostly I have almost everything figured out for the app but I need to add to the app a way to sign in and sign up to the website and also a way to pay with credit card. I don't know how to start with all that.

I have tried to look some videos but I didn't see anything similar to what I want to do. I would really appreciate if you could explain me it, or send me some kind of help.

Comment: Apple prefers that people don't make apps just for websites. They might reject your app when you submit it. An alternative would be making a mobile version of your site.

Comment: More than a website is like business, so people can buy tickets for concerts and stuff...

Comment: Hire a professional, it's what we do.

Comment: Yes.. but if I can try I save me that money would be great! and also I want to learn to program on ios better.

Comment: Learning is great, but you are only going to waste time and money by not getting it done in a timely manner, and by not getting it done correctly. Just something to think about. Some developers also may offer access to the source code; which you could use as a learning tool.

Comment: I understand that, but I want to try it by myself and if I can't make it I'll hire someone. I don't need it right now, I will need it on summer or maybe after summer. Right now I don't have the money to hire a professional.

Comment: Understandable. You should browse [github](http://www.github.com). There are a ton of open source projects on there. For credit cards, Paypal has a decent API for accepting payments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I can't help you with sign-up/in features, I do know that [ZooZ](http://www.zooz.com) seems to be the cheapest and easiest way to accept credit card payments on mobile apps.

Both iOS and Android compatible, ZooZ's 3 lines of code monetizes your app in minutes. Users have their choice of checking out with credit cards or PayPal.

The biggest advantages of ZooZ are that your user always stays within your app and won't have to re-enter payment details in the future, resulting in faster processing and higher conversion rates.

Of course you can always build your own credit card processing platform, but considering the challenges of security, merchant accounts, and PCI compliance, it's probably not worth the headache.

Full disclosure: I have the privilege of working at ZooZ :)

Good luck with your app!